# Remove values from url using php

Tags: php

I am appending the values to url in order to pass them to a next page using  tag. I want to remove those appended values once I access them on the next page without reloading the page.
Is there anyway to do that in php?
I want to display the updated url in the browser.

Comment: To change what appears in the browser's address bar will always require a reload. Perhaps you should `POST` instead of `GET`?

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski : So there is no way to change the url appearing in the browser without reloading the page.

Comment: No, because that would enable any site to masquerade as any other site by modifying the address bar :) Non-ideal situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`parse_url()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) to split the URL into its components and put the components that you want back together to form the new URL.

If you want to modify the query string, call [`parse_str()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php) on it, passing an array as second parameter, and modify that array.

Comment: As per the comments above this will require the reloading the page.

Comment: Manipulating PHP strings does not require reloading the page. Manipulating the contents of the address bar does, but I see no indication that the OP wants to manipulate the contents of the address bar.

Answer (score 0):

```
str_replace ( $search-param ,  $replace-param , $subject [, int &$count ] )
```

or use `parse_url()`